# Can't install cx_Freeze on linux mint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cx-freeze, linux-mint

Trying to install the the third-party Python module cx_Freeze on linux mint for python 3.8, keep getting this error:

```
dc@dc-ThinkPad2-T470:~/PycharmProjects/untitled$ sudo apt-get install python3-cx_Freeze
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-cx_Freeze
```

This method of installation with `sudo apt-get install` has worked smoothly for me for other third party modules such as Pillow, don't know why not working for cx_Freeze.
Would greatly appreciate a helpful answer, been trying to install for hours.
Thanks

Comment: That's more suited to askubuntu.com, it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any one of the following command based on your `pip` version

```
pip install cx-Freeze
pip3 install cx-Freeze
```

It worked for me. I am using Linux Mint 20.1